# Is there any way to send an array or list to sidebarMenu in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

In RShiny is there any way to send an array or list of menuItems to sidebarMenu?

```
dashboardSidebar(width = 180,
   sidebarMenu(
     menuItem("server1", tabName = "server1", icon = icon("server")),
     menuItem("server2", tabName = "server2", icon = icon("server")),
     menuItem("server3", tabName = "server3", icon = icon("server"))
     )
)
```

I actually have to add about 30 or menuItems to add and the names will change over time. This is also an issue with sending multiple fluidRows to a tabItem. Hopefully, the same solution can apply to both.

Comment: `renderUI` might be what you are looking for

Comment: This should help: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#dynamic-content

Comment: Thanks @Carl, this worked for me; it works when applied to sidebarMenuOutput as well

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to use `uiOutput`, but personally, I am not a fan. However, there is not a single solution for all dynamic element additions, especially when not using `uiOutput`.

Here is a minimal solution that does what you said you wanted, but I guess this is only the first step for you (since I don't think you really just want to add `menuItems`). If you are looking for a more customized answer, please edit your original post with your actual problems.

You can add `menuItems` to the sidebar very easily, if you use JavaScript/jQuery. This is mainly because `menuItems` are not really "connected" to the Shiny-App but merely toggle buttons. It gets more difficult if you wanted to add complex reactive elements.

There is basically the trick that you give the target element (sidebar) an Id for easy selection and add the HTML that is generated by the shiny ui functions. The `customMessageHandler` gets both components and tells the browser to create the element.

More on `customMessageHandlers` can be found [here](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/).

Sample code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 180,
    sidebarMenu(id = "nice",
      menuItem("server1", tabName = "server1", icon = icon("server")),
      menuItem("server2", tabName = "server2", icon = icon("server")),
      menuItem("server3", tabName = "server3", icon = icon("server"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    actionButton("button", "Add MenuItem"),
    tags$script("
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('addMenuItem', function(message){
        $('#' + message[0]).append(message[1]);
      })
    ")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  addMenuItem <- function(item, sidebarId){
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "addMenuItem", message = list(sidebarId, as.character(item)))
  }    

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    newId <- as.numeric(input$button) + 3
    newMenuItem <- menuItem(paste0("server", newId), tabName = paste0("server", newId), icon = icon("server"))
    addMenuItem(newMenuItem, "nice")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```